# Angular 6/7 circular dependency between libraries

Tags: angular, angular6, circular-dependency, angular7

I'm working on a project that's using Angular 7 and I have various angular libraries for the respective modules of the application that I build then publish on (a private) npm to be used by the application. So all angular libraries are imported in the app through their npm package.

The problem I'm facing is that I now have 2 modules that import each other because they need to show a component from the other module. I cannot move said components elsewhere because they depend on services and other components in their own module.

To try and make it a little bit clearer I will give you an example of my situation.

I already have a `SharedModule` with some independent components that are used in other modules, then I also have a module for each API service. So I have a `UsersModule`, 'AdministrationModule' and such. My problem is with `PlantModule` and `FleetModule`.

- Plant as in power plant
- Fleet as in a group of plants and/or other
  fleets, but also has own properties

`PlantModule` has a component for the list of plants (as in power plants not organic plants) and a component for the details of the plant. In the detail component there are also other external components that show for example all users assigned to it as well as the fleets.

`FleetsModule` also has a component for the list of fleets and one for the details. In this detail component there are also external components like the users assigned, a list of sub-fleets and a list of plants that are part of the fleet.

What I'm trying to do is to have reusable components to be used in other modules so that I don't need to copy-paste all the API services, components and such everywhere.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to solve it?

### UPDATE

In order to solve it I changed the structure of the "pages" where those components are needed. So instead of importing the reusable components inside other components in the libraries I create a wrapper view in the main app and import all I need.

Comment: you may create `SharedModule` for reusable part and, on your app.module you pick up what you need from each modules.

Comment: I would suggest rethinking your library structure, and decoupling it. Does it make sense for `office-supplies-module` to import something from `desk-module`? Probably not. 

It looks like you have a state problem. Maybe try moving the state management   in to your app (rather than a library) for tracking which desk the supplies belong to.

Comment: @Yanis-git I already have a SharedModule that's independent of the others and should stay like that, the components I need have dependencies on their respective modules

Comment: @hevans900 my bad, poor description... I will update now to hopefulyl make it clearer

Answer (score -1):

So you have three modules, `DeskModule`, `UsersModule`, and `OfficeSuppliesModule`.

The `DeskModule` imports `UsersModule` and `OfficeSuppliesModule` as it has two show their components in a Component of this module.

And the problem is that in `OfficeSuppliesModule` you have a component from the `DeskModule` to show which desk it belongs to.

I didn't quite get as to why do you have a component just to show that? Instead of a component, you could have leveraged a service that you could use in the `CoreModule`. From this service, you could expose a method to tell the template of the component in the `OfficeSuppliesModule` which desk those office supplies belong to. Since there wouldn't be a Component that needs to be re-used, you wouldn't face this issue.

Another thing you can do is to move the component that you're using both in your `DeskModule` and your `OfficeSuppliesModule` to the SharedModule and then add the `SharedModule` to the `imports` array of both the `DeskModule` and the `OfficeSuppliesModule`

### UPDATE

Since Angular 6, you can add `providedIn: 'root'` to the `@Injectable` decorator instead of adding the service name to the `providers` array of the module. That way, the service is registered to the `root` injector and is available throughtout the App.

So you can change all those services you'd want in the multiple modules by adding `providedIn: 'root'` to the `@Injectable` decorator of those services:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

And then as suggested above this update, move the components used in the `PlantModule` and the `FleetsModule` to the `SharedModule`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description, I just updated it to hopefully make it clearer.
I can't move the components to the SharedModule because they depend on services and other components in their module to function and I don't want my SharedModule to import other modules or have things that aren't meant to be shared

Comment: Reading your question again, would you consider moving the `PlantComponent` and the `UserComponent` to the `SharedModule`? That would be an ideal thing to do as it's being used in the PlantModule and the `FleetsModule`

Comment: The problem is that those components rely on the API, so I would also need to copy the API service into shared module wich then would become the whole application basically. If those components were independent I wouldn't have a problem, but the goal of the application is to have those separate modules, that even though import other modules, to contain all they need to function and be reused even in a different application

Comment: @Marcus, actually, you can use `providedIn: 'root'` in the `@Injectable` decorator of those services to add them to the root injector. In that case, those services would be available throughout the app. This is possible in Angular 6 and 7.(`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`)

Comment: Yes but I would then need to import the packages which contain the module in `SharedModule` so it would create a circular dependency between shared and the other modules

Comment: Why would you need to inject the modules if you already have those components declared in the `SharedModule` and those services provided in the `root` Injector?

Comment: I'm really sorry, it was a busy day so I just misused some terms. Since the angular library is packaged as an npm package, when I use anything from it I import the package like `"@my-company/fleets"`, that means that to use the service in the `SharedModule` I would have to do

`import { MyService } from '@my-company/fleets'` for example.

But talking about it made me thing that I could package the services separately and do as you suggested